# How to add image alt attribute to the thumbnail code

Tags: images

My theme has got a code that looks like this:-

```php
<div class="bs-info-author-block py-4 px-3 mb-4 flex-column justify-content-center text-center">
            
    <a class="bs-author-pic mb-3" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ));?>"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID') , 150); ?></a>
        <div class="flex-grow-1">
            <h2 class="title"><?php esc_html_e('By','blogus'); ?> <a href ="<?php echo esc_url(get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ));?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></h2>
            <p><?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></p>
        </div>
</div>
```

I would like this code to make the author posted by, thumbnail image to have alt text. Here is production page, ([why mobile phone is regarded as a computer](https://sopriza.com/why-mobile-phone-is-regarded-as-a-computer/))

Thanks

Comment: [As documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/), you can specify the alt text in the 4th argument to `get_avatar()`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, please if you have code example, i could apply

Comment: <p><?php the_author_meta( 'description' );  get_avatar( $alt = '',); ?> </p> something like that, correct?

Comment: <?php echo get_avatar( $alt = 'Profile', get_the_author_meta( 'ID') , 150); ?></a> all trial i made none worked ☹️